# Trace HapiJS Unhandled Routes

Tags: logging, routes, hapi.js

Is there any way to trace URL that is GET-ed from my HapiJS server?

I have one or two "error not found" in my console (which refers to unhandled URL path). I'm quite sure it's the routes that I don't implement, coz I put console.log in every routing path that I made.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like https://github.com/hapijs/good and https://github.com/hapijs/good-console to log and output the calls to your server.